# IR Connector for Sharp

Tags: infrared, connector

I bought one of these, and forgot to get the connector.
http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/categories.php?c=139

Now I need to buy a hall effect sensor and was thinking/looking at mouser, Does anyone know the partnumber of a cable/connector similar to [this](http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=8733):

[image]

OR how I would go about figuring out said connector p/n at other places too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connector is made by JST, as the linked page says.  I know from looking at it and using lots of JST connectors that it's PH series connector, but you can also find that by looking at [this](http://www.sparkfun.com/commerce/product_info.php?products_id=9750) Sparkfun page, or by (tediously) looking through Digikey and JST catalogs.

The plastic part of the connector you linked is called a "housing", and it holds the crimp terminals that are crimped onto the wire, and which slide over the housing.  That one is part number PHR-3 (PH series, rectangular (1x3), three terminal).  You can get it from Digikey [here](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=455-1126-ND), or from Future Electronics.  **Mouser isn't a JST distributor.**

However, you'll definitely need the terminals that go with it.  They're P/N [SPH-002T-P0.5S](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=455-1127-1-ND) for the 24-30 gauge wire. (You'll also need stranded wire for this.  The picture is nice and big on the Digikey site, but the terminal is TINY.

Unless you have [this](http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?Detail&name=455-1128-ND) $400+ tool, you cannot effectively crimp these terminals.  Note that I've sucessfully crimped these terminals with a PA series crimper, if you happen to have one of those on hand... You need to strip as little insulation as possible (The long tabs grip the insulation and provide strain relief, while the short ones grip the wire), a good hand on your soldering iron, and plenty of flux on both the terminal and the wire.  It can be done.

What you need instead is a KR-series connector.  They're IDC style, (Insulation displacement connector) so you don't need to do any crimping.  The datasheet is here:
http://www.jst-mfg.com/product/pdf/eng/eKR.pdf
and you'll easily see from the datasheet that what you want has the part number 03KR-6H-P.  Unfortunately, Digikey doesn't keep these on hand.  Finding them is left as an exercise to the reader.

All that being said, I've also used the Sharp IR distance sensors before I had access to the crimp tool at my current place of employment, and simply desoldered the existing connector, soldered on my own wires, and hot-glued the assembly to prevent strain on the wires.

Comment: A fine answer, Nivek! +1 for pulling off the existing connector and soldering on wires. I hate those damn JST connectors.

Comment: @Ping - I love JST connectors. I use them almost every day.  However, I have the crimp tool. PS My name is Kevin.

Comment: Yeah, if I had the crimp tool, I'd probably feel differently. PS Sorry about misspelling your name. I had kind of guessed your name was Kevin, but I thought it was funnier to call you Nivek.

Comment: I've successfully crimped those connectors with a $8.95 jameco crimper( http://www.jameco.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/Product_10001_10001_99443_-1 ). It's a lot more labor-intensive, and the resulting crimp doesn't look very nice, but it is certainly sturdy enough to un-mate the connector out by gripping just the wires

Comment: I haven't looked into just desoldering the connector, that might just be the right idea I'm looking for. Can't believe I didn't think of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the part number, but I believe those are JST connectors: http://www.jst-mfg.com/index_e.php My best guess is the ZH series, but that's really just a guess from the picture.

Mouser is not a distributor for JST, though they may carry a clone of the connector you're looking for. Digikey does carry JST stuff, including the ZH series.

Maybe ask in the Sparkfun IRC channel or forum?

(Please post the part number as a comment if you do track it down.)

Comment: I guess I would feel ackward asking sparkfun to give me the P/N of a part they sell on another distributor. Which is why I asked over here instead.